# I'm using an array sort function to sort a nodelist but there is a lag when I try to append the array a parent node. Can I do this more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, destructuring

See snippet of code below. I get the element nodes first and store them in a 'paragraph' variable. I then sort the array. Then I make clear the innerHTML of the parent element. I then loop through each item in the array and append it to the parent element. The issue is that I have 5000 elements that I need to append to the parent element and there is a clear lag of a few seconds when you click the sort button on my front end application to trigger this. Is there a way of programming this differently so it runs quicker.

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  chronological.addEventListener('click', ()=> {  
    const paragraph = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wimesParagraph')];
    const sectionSix = document.querySelector('.sectionSix');
    paragraph.sort((a,b)=> a.children[0].dataset.number - b.children[0].dataset.number);
    sectionSix.innerHTML = ""
    paragraph.forEach((para)=> {
        sectionSix.appendChild(para)
    })
})
```

I tried destructuring the array and appending it to the parent element but it didn't work.

Comment: appending in a loop isn't very efficient as each iteration triggers a DOM update. You can use just [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to avoid the loop. `sectionSix.innerHTML = ""; sectionSix.append(...paragraph);`

Comment: Try and create a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) first, append the elements to that, and then append the DocumentFragment to the `sectionSix` element afterwards.

Comment: quick [benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/24925/0/js-append-vs-appendchild-multiple-nodes). Looks like `append()` is fastest and `document.fragment` is slower than your existing loop. (Brave v. 1.50.121 MacOS)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these suggestions. I tried the sectionSix.append(...paragraph). It is quicker but there is still a bit of lag but I can probably live with it.